Laravel Websocket URL provide for Frontend ( React js or fluttter )
I'm studying Laravel real time, and I want to provide the frontend websockets url, but I'm not sure how to do so. Could you please help me? Am I doing something incorrectly? Is there any git repos i can learn?
I'm using BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher to run my websocket server in local.
I ran this url to connect websocket "http://127.0.0.1:8000/laravel-websockets"
I also connected with React js too using socket.io but there's error .
"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:6001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P0Bfm60. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 404."
I've config in middleware, config.cors in laravel but it still show this error.

You can't use the socket.io client to connect to a pusher server, socket.io has a "protocol" which your server should implement and in this case it is not, here is how you should use it https://pusher.com/tutorials/web-notifications-laravel-pusher-channels/#creating-the-application-views

thank you. i want to intergrate it with frontend framework like react js by provide api for them is there any document i can read?

You don't need a special library for react, you can just use it normally, here is an example of that, but it can change based on your structure and requirements https://pusher.com/tutorials/react-websockets/#parent-container-component-appjs

thank you so much! is there anyway i can publish my laravel websockets url without using pusher?
